# Receiving Resource object instead of value using Node and Angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, nested, angular-promise

I am trying to get the value returned through an authorization getCurrentUser function. When calling the function, I get this resource holding a Promise. I can see the _id value in there! How do I access it?

Thank you in advance!
[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4hTN.png)

Here's a bit of the Auth service where getCurrentUser is defined:

```
(function config() {
  function AuthService($location, $http, $cookies, $q, appConfig, Util, User) {
    const safeCb = Util.safeCb;
    let currentUser = {};
    let Auth = {};
    const LOCAL_HOST = 'localhost';

    if ($cookies.get('token') && $location.path() !== '/logout') {
      currentUser = User.get();
    }

    Auth = {
      getCurrentUser(callback) {
      if (arguments.length === 0) {
        return currentUser;
      }

      const value = currentUser.hasOwnProperty('$promise') ? currentUser.$promise : currentUser;
      return $q.when(value).then(user => {
        safeCb(callback)(user);
        return user;
      }, () => {
        safeCb(callback)({});
        return {};
      });
    }
...
```

Here is where I call it:

```
    angular.module('toroApp').directive('csvreaderDirective', ['$http', function ($http, Auth) {

      return {
        controller(Auth) {
          const currentUser = Auth.getCurrentUser();
          console.log(currentUser);
        },
        compile(element, Auth) {
    ...
```

Comment: Please show ur code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auth.getCurrentUser() is returning a [$q promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) so you need to use the promise API to get the result.

```
controller(Auth) {
    Auth.getCurrentUser().then(function (user) {
        const currentUser = user;
        console.log(currentUser);
    });
}
```